# svn:externals with matching revisions

Tags: svn, svn-externals

Suppose I have some `svn:externals` set up to pull in some resources from elsewhere in my repository:

```
../../path/to/scripts scripts
../../path/to/data data
```

I want each part of a working copy to all come from the same revision, so I don't want to pin these externals to a particular revision number.  If I simply do an `svn up`, this works like I'd want it to:

```
Fetching external item into 'scripts':
External at revision 15000.

Fetching external item into 'scripts':
External at revision 15000.

At revision 15000.
```

However, if I try to check out a particular revision (using something like `svn up -r 144444`), the externals still come from the latest revision:

```
Fetching external item into 'scripts':
External at revision 15000.

Fetching external item into 'scripts':
External at revision 15000.

At revision 14444.
```

Is there some `svn:externals` syntax or some canned script or command that I can use to easily update a working copy, including all of its externals, to a particular revision?

(In particular, I don't want to do `svn --ignore-externals`, because I want to also update the externals to a particular revision, and I don't want to peg the externals to a fixed revision, because I generally want them to track HEAD.)

Comment: [This script](https://gist.github.com/Orangenhain/3413952) (which I haven't tried) is one approach to automating a checkout of a particular revision of a directory and its externals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There **are not** easy way without PEGged externals (and maintain "always HEAD" with pegged externals is a/ easy b/ handwork with possible automation)

For "time-back machine" with not-pegged externals in order to return state of the whole WC to the state at revision N in master repo you have to perform:

- in wrapper-WC `svn log -l 1 -r N` and write timestamp `DATE` of this revision
- For **each** externals in each externals WC `svn log -l 1 -r {'DATE'}` and write revision number (X,Y,Z)
- `svn up -r N`
- `svn up -r (X|Y|Z)` in WCs of externals

Resulting mixed Working Copy will be neeed for you result (not 100% guarantee, because between revisions N and N+1 revisions of externals *may be* also *updated*, but you haven't traces of it)

Comment: To clarify, each of my externals comes from elsewhere in the same repository, so concerns like matching dates and externals getting commits between revisions N and N+1 of the master repo don't apply. But thanks for the confirmation that there's no automated way of doing this.

Comment: @JoshKelleyv - well, for the single repository time-back **can be** automated with rather short bash, because extracted date will be used with all externals (and all externals you can get with `svn pg -R`)